# By now and by this time

Tags: usage

Are **by now** and **by this time** interchangeable.

1. He hasn't called me by now.
2. He hasn't called me by this time.
3. He has called me by now.

Is the third sentence correct?

Comment: Better would be   " He hasn't called me yet" and "He has called me already"

Comment: Or "...so far", "...as of now", or probably others.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly. "Now" is the clearly specified moment that it's stated.
"By this time" is more usually used with *other* than the present tense. E.G.:

> If he hasn't called me by this time *tomorrow*, I'll call him.

Comment: Is the third sentence correct?

Comment: It's *grammatically* correct, though unusual: it only makes sense in the context of *not knowing* if the caller has called yet, relying only on the time.